# How to insert even if 'after insert' trigger rises an error?

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

Error thrown by the 'after insert' trigger causes the insert to fail. How can I skip this behavior?

I've created an `AFTER INSERT` trigger and i see that if it throws an error, insert will be failed, but i need to proceed the insert statement anyway(!!!)

How can i allow the insert query to go through even if trigger rises error?

Comment: Why would you want such behavior? What does your trigger do that it doesn't matter if it fires correctly? It is a best practice to rollback if the trigger fails. Not wanting it to happen is a design smell to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any details of triggers in MS SQL Server, but I think you should be able to get your intended behavior with a [try-catch block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) in the trigger.